# Поиск Unicode символа в строке

Tags: php

Нужно в строке найти символ ▒. Пробовал

```
explode("▒", $string);
```

`stristr($string, "▒");`

Но эти методы не справились с задачей.
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Попробуйте [strpos()](http://www.php.su/strpos) функцию. Либо функцией ord() получаете код символа и перебором посимвольно строки проверяете на его наличие.

Comment: Тогда уж `mb_strpos`